# Gmapping noise in map

Tags: slam, navigation, erratic-gazebo, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

i am using erratic robot in Gazebo and taking laser scan after that using gmapping i create a map which looks like [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/zulqarnain320/6917372367/)

i cant figure out that why the map has noise in it or unexplored places since before i was trying with basic_localization_stage.bag [can find here](http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/gmapping/) the map was perfect.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28088/gmapping-noise-in-map/) by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-02-21**:
What type of laser scanner are you using? Specifically, what is its max range?

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2012-02-21**:
it is sick lms 200 with max range 32 m practically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gray areas you see in the middle are "unknown" which can mean they are unexplored, or you only got a few scans in those areas and gmapping didn't clear them out. This is perfectly normal, and if you know those areas are clear, you can open your map up in an image editor and mark them as such. The map format is described in more detail in the [map_server](http://ros.org/wiki/map_server#Image_format) wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1